# searching for a substring of a word that starts with and ends with

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array with the names of the controllers of my php app and i need to get the first word out of the name for example i have:

TenantController
TenantMetasController
DealerTenant

I'm trying to retrieve the first substring that starts with an uppercase letter and ends with a lowercase letter , before the next uppercase letter

so if i have "TenantController" i want to retrieve "Tenant" as a prefix

I tried to search for regular expression but it doesnt seem to be of help for what i want to do

Thank you

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/L2uQ1J/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using preg_split like below:

```
// String 
$str = 'TenantController';

// Split the string to array using preg_split().
$pieces = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/',$str);

/**
 * Since The first letter of your modal is probably an uppercase,
 * the preg_split() is going to have the first array item as empty.
 * This function array_shift() will delete that first item.
 */
array_shift($pieces);

// display the result.
dd($pieces);
```

Comment: Did by any chance this solution work for you!?

Answer (score -2):

```
$t = 'DealerTenant';
$sub_string = substr($t,strpos($t,'T'),strpos($t,'t')+1));
```

try this

Comment: This only works with one fixed word. The question supplies a few examples and you can see that they all have different letters after the first section, which is to be selected.

Comment: "Try this" does not make for a good answer. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.